# Firebase goOffline() fires too early

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why does the following happen?

When executing

```
db.ref('einstellungen').update({[set + "_blue"]:true}).then(firebase.database().goOffline());
```

nothing happens - no error, no upload.

This, however,

```
db.ref('einstellungen').update({[set + "_blue"]: true}).then().then(function(){
            firebase.database().goOffline();
});
```

works without any problems...

Comment: try `db.ref('einstellungen').update({[set + "_blue"]:true}).then(function(){firebase.database().goOffline()});`

Comment: This probably works - why? remains...

Comment: it seems like you're passing `firebase.database().goOffline()` instead of a lambda function to `then()` in your first code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line actually goes offline straight away:

```
db.ref('einstellungen').update({[set + "_blue"]:true})
  .then(firebase.database().goOffline());
```

If you watch carefully, you're passing the result from calling `goOffline()` into the `then()` call, so it has to evaluate `goOffline()` straight away.

Instead you'll need to declare a callback:

```
db.ref('einstellungen').update({[set + "_blue"]:true})
  .then(() => firebase.database().goOffline());
```

In this second snippet the `goOffline()` is in the *body* of the callback function, so it only gets evaluated once the `then()` callback is actually invoked, which is after the update completes.